# How to get displayName from lastSuccessfulBuild in Jenkinsfile groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins 

def job_data = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME)
     
       if (job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild()) {
                println 'LastSuccessNumber: ' + job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()
                println 'LastSuccessResult: ' + job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().result
                println 'LastSuccessJobDisplayName: ' + job_data.job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().displayName
          
}
```

I have above code working except third println:

```
println 'LastSuccessJobDisplayName: ' + 
job_data.job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().displayName
```

I also tried:

```
println 'LastSuccessJobDisplayName: ' + 
job_data.job_data.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getDisplayName()
```

but still not working. How could I get the displayName of a lastSuccessfulBuild()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rest api call resolved it: <job_url>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json